# Solving a PDE; question on rewritting its form

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Can I get some hints on going about resolving the notation in the following PDE, from Gockenback's books I believe, so that I can approach it: $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} -\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[u^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right]=0. $$

I'm not sure what to do about about the differential operator acting on $ u^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} $; reviewing the chain rule, I don't immediately see how I would do this. A quick explanation and example of this would be nice.

If I could just rewrite the PDE in a form like, $A\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+ B\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} + C\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+ D\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+E u' = G(x,t)$; with $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$ being **whatever coefficients (I'm not assuming they would be linear)** they need to be and $G(x,t) = 0$, then I think I could start studying how to solve it if it can be (most PDEs are not explicitly solvable). The best I can hope for is numerically approximate it on some interval of validity. I don't have the skill to make an analytical study of the PDE .

Comment: First, what do you mean by “solve” here? Finding an explicit solution, proving existence and uniqeness, or what? Do you have any intitial and/or boundary conditions? Where did you encounter this PDE? (Provide [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960), you know!) Do you have any reason to believe that it's possible to solve it explicitly? It's a *nonlinear* PDE, so you can't write it in the form that you mentioned (if you want the coefficients to depend only on $x$ and $t$).

Comment: Thank you. I'll rewrite my last sentence to explicitly state the fact that most partial differential equations do not have a solution. But studying the existence of a explicit, analytic, or numerical approximation is secondary to understanding how to resolve the notation so that I can at least start working with the problem.

Comment: Resolve the notation? It's just the $x$-derivative of $u^2 u_x$, so what is there to resolve? You can expand it with the Leibniz rule if you think that makes it better:$$(u^2 u_x)_x = (u^2)_x u_x + u^2 (u_x)_x = (2u u_x) u_x + u^2 u_{xx} = 2 u u_x^2 + u^2 u_{xx}.$$

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, I really appreciate it. I have never used that rule and have only seen it used for differentiating under the integral sign using the FTC, when dealing with Green's functions (which I never have)- I will have to learn it finally.

Comment: What? It's just the good old product rule for derivatives from calculus, $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$, so it would be quite bizarre if you hadn't learned that rule before studying PDEs... But anyway, you're welcome! :-)

Comment: By the way, if you're going to use finite differences, note that $u^2 u_x = (\tfrac13 u^3)_x$, so that $(u^2 u_x)_x = (\frac13 u^3)_{xx}$, so you could perhaps use the centered-difference approximation to the second derivative directly on $\frac13 u^3$.

Comment: Aha, you've cleared up two confusions; Leibniz rule, I always think "Leibniz rule for differentiation under integral sign" instead of "the product rule". The other confusion was writing it out like that even though "$u$" is an unknown function. For instance, I might take your suggestion and do a centered difference approximation for lets say $0< x < 1$- but what lets me use Taylor's series for the unknown function? I know that the problem may have came from a book, so its reasonable to assume the functions analytic or has continuous partials, but in practice,  I get weary of what I can do.